# Environment variables added to virtualenv 'activate' script not found (mac)

Tags: python, macos, environment-variables, virtualenv

After adding the environment variable `export MYVAR="OK"` to the activate script in `bin/activate`, they are not found when running

```
import os
os.environ["MYVAR"]
```

(The python script is run after activating the virtual env.)

However, if I run `export MYVAR =="OK"` in the terminal and afterwards run the program the variable is found. Why is this? How do I tell python to look for env variables in the activate script as well?

Comment: Just to make sure the env is set before blaming it on python, can you test by running ```echo $MYVAR``` in terminal and make sure it gives ```OK``` as output, otherwise it's not set and therefore problem not related to python code

Comment: If you provide also you activate script after adding the export, It will help narrow down the problem